# Passing SLURM batch command line arguments to R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, pbs, slurm

I'm trying to run a SLURM sbatch command with various parameters that I can read in an R script. When using PBS system, I used to write `qsub -v param1=x,param2=y` (+ other system parameters like the memory requirements etc and the script name to be read by PBS) and then in the R script read it with `x = Sys.getenv(‘param1’)`.

Now I tried

```
sbatch run.sh --export=basePath=‘a’
```

With run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR
echo $PWD

module load R/common/3.3.3

R CMD BATCH --quiet --no-restore --no-save runDo.R output.txt
```

And runDo.R:

```
base.path = Sys.getenv('basePath')

print(base.path)
```

The script is running but the argument value is not assigned to base.path variable (it prints an empty string).

Comment: I just know about R so forgive me if it's irrelevant, but if you're getting the output of the script you may want to try `cat` instead of `print` as the output of `print` will start with `"[1]"` and will leave escape characters in the path (`"\\"` for `"\"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The export parameter has to be passed to sbatch not to the run.sh script.

It should be like this:

```
sbatch --export=basePath=‘a’ run.sh
```